# PHP "permanent variable"

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, permanent

I'm currently working at a WordPress Plugin.
It supports shortcode and creates DOM elements, when the shortcode is called.

Now my problem:
I want to identify the elements.

So when the shortcode gets called the first time it should return something like

```
<div class="myClass-0"></div>
```

and when it gets called the second time

```
<div class="myClass-1"></div>
```

And so on.

Any ideas on this issue?
Thanks for help

Julian.

Comment: Without code - yes, create a global variable and increment it every time you invoke the "shortcode". Use its value for the counter part of your class. Since there's no code from your part, I hope you'll know how to implement it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [static variable](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static). A static variable holds its value globally and is preserved between function calls:

```
function doSomething() {
    static $i = 0;
    ##############

    return $i++;
}

doSomething(); // 0
doSomething(); // 1
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/JlcfE7v8) It will work in class methods too, of course, though depending on the situation you might be better off using an instance variable.

Comment: I tested your code. But unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems like WordPress deletes all variables from this script.

Comment: My code was just `if(!$classID){$classID = 0;}else{$classID++;}` But as I just answered, I fixed the issue using an other idea.

Comment: @Julian: Your problem here is actually the `!$classID` part. `!0` is `true`, and so `$classID` will always be `0`. Use `if(!isset($classID))` instead and it should work.

Comment: I tried `if(!isset($classID)){$classID = 0;}else{$classID++;}` But this didn't work. But I'm fine with my random solution!

Comment: @Julian: Well, I'm not. The chance is actually high enough that they'll be the same. Can you post your entire code, please? Because that really was an issue.

Comment: `$myClass = jw_rand(5);` and the function: `function jw_rand($length)
{
    $return = "";
    for($b = 0; $b < $length; $b++)
    {
        $return .= mt_rand(0,9);
    }
    return $return;
}` I don't agree with you. When I take a random number (mt_rand() is  the better random function in PHP) between 0 and 9 five times, there is just a little chance to get the same. When I do `jw_rand(10)` the chance is actually much lower.

Comment: @Julian: I know. It's like finding collisions in MD5. The chance is one in billions, yet, collisions have been found. Wouldn't you rather a bulletproof solution?

Comment: I would. But it seems like WordPress is deleting all kinds of variables. So I think there is no bulletproof way for doing this in wordpress

Comment: @Julian: There's always a bulletproof way :) How about `if(!$classID){$classID = 0;} $classID++;`?

Comment: If you'd read the whole conversation, you surely recognized my comment on Jan 27 at 15:39, that does exactly what you wrote, with the difference that my code keeps the first, initial value, "0"

Comment: @Julian: I can't help you if you don't want help.

Comment: Why I don't want help?! I just said that I already tried what you recommended.

Comment: @Julian: Logically, your code will stay at `0` forever. I suggested a fix. I'd like to see a code example to reproduce the problem, please... [See? Doesn't work.](http://codepad.org/Vm2TkE9r)

Comment: Wow. Now I see that it doesn't work my way. But can you explain why the variable is unset but has a value when I call the function the second time?

Comment: @Julian: No. I can't reproduce the problem because I don't know what your plugin looks like! Please post some code!

Comment: @hakre: I feel obligated to notify you: *its =)

Answer (score 0):

If you need between the different request, There is no permanent variable in php You should use session or database for this requirement.

Comment: I tried using session variables. But this didn't work too. I don't know, how the wordpress implementation of plugins work. So I can't imagine why none of my attempts worked.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing of your Ideas worked for me.

WordPress seems to delete all static and non-staitc variables.
And session variables too.

Now I got a new idea and fixed the issue by using random numbers.
I wrote this function:

```
function jw_rand($length)
{
    $return = "";
    for($a = 0; $a < $length; $a++)
    {
        $return .= mt_rand(0,9);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Then I call it via `<?php echo("<div class=\"myClass-".jw_rand(5)."\"></div>"); ?>`

This doesn't count my classes... But at least I can identify the divs.
And I don't think that the chance is high for two identical results of this function.

Thanks for help though.
Maybe some WordPress pro can answer my question, explaining how the plugin- and shortcode integration works and why variables disappear after calling the plugin once.

Greets
Julian